# Wierd Space Between Divs - HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

[image]

Why does my code creates this wied spaces between divs.

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">       
        <p class="header_title">Theme Preview</p>
        <p class="header_quote">Previewing Another Blog</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="post">
        <p class="post_title"></p>
        <hr />
        <p> <span class="post_date"></span> <span class="post_autor"></span> </p>
        <div class="post_content">      
        </div>
        <hr class="post_final" />
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <p>Design by</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:
    body {
        width:100%;
        background-color:#C1C8D0;
        height:auto;
    }

```
#container {
    margin:auto;
    max-width:1600px;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}

#header {
    background-color:#1B1C1E;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    text-align:center;
}

.header_title {
    padding-top:5%;
    color:white;
    font-family:Agency FB;
    font-size:5em;
    text-align:center;
}

.header_quote {
    color:#EBEBEB;
    font-family:Agency FB;
    font-size:1em;
    text-align:center;
    padding-bottom:5%;
}

#menu {
    background-color:white;
}
```

I already looked the CSS and I did not wrote any margin or something related to crate blank spaces.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are not resetting the CSS, so each browser may render the CSS differently. To avoid that, I recommend to use a **[CSS reset file](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.css)** which need to be included before all CSS files. This file resets all the styles which may be applied by different browsers to a consistent baseline.

As a "hot-fix" you can still do this, but as mentioned it's more common to use a CSS reset.

Add `margin: 0;` to `.header_quote` and add following CSS rule

```
#menu > ul{
    margin: 0;
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rwachtler/jma69u74/)**

Answer (score 0):

I think it the p tag

```
p{margin: 0;}
```

Comment: This is a little terse.  Please include some explanation of why you think this is the problem.